# Angular 2: set hover properties using ngStyle

Tags: angular, ng-style

I am trying to set the hover property states using `[ngStyle]`.

The following only sets the normal state colors. When I mouse over the button, the button does not change to the pressed colors as expected.

```
<button (click)="logout()" 
    class="btn register-button"
    [ngStyle]=" hover ? 
        {'color': theme.logoutButtonColorPressed,
         'border-color': theme.logoutButtonBorderColorPressed,
         'background-color': theme.logoutButtonBackgroundColorPressed}:
        {'color': theme.logoutButtonColorNormal,
         'border-color': theme.logoutButtonBorderColorNormal,
         'background-color': theme.logoutButtonBackgroundColorNormal}"> 
    Logout
</button>
```

Comment: what is `hover ` here `[ngStyle]=" hover {`?

Comment: it's not clear what you want. if you want to switch styles on hover, add the following to the button `<button (mouseover)="hover=true" (mouseleave)="hover=false"`...

Comment: I am trying to replicate the CSS....

.logout-container button:hover {
}

hoping to set the colors for the button for the hover state. I can set these manually using 

.logout-container button:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00) !important;
    border-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

Comment: Your solution works a treat: The solution is as follows:

    <button (click)="logout()" 
                        class="btn  register-button"
                        (mouseover)="hover=true" 
                        (mouseleave)="hover=false"
                        [ngStyle]="  hover?  ( rest of... style as per above...)>Logout</button>

Comment: I posted it as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42324336/2545680). You can upvote or accept it if it helped.

Comment: is there anything I can add to my answer?

Answer (score 18):

If you want to switch styles on hover, add the following to the button

```
<button (mouseover)="hover=true" (mouseleave)="hover=false"...
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are in need of selecting individual buttons by changing ngstyle, this is what I did.

**btn.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="socketData && socketData.status === 'ok'">
    <div *ngFor="let button of socketData.message; let i = index"
         [ngStyle]="hovered === i ? pressedStyle(button) : buttonStyle(button)"
         (mouseover)="hovered = i"
         (mouseout)="hovered = -1"
         (click)="reqTicket(button.id)">

      {{button.someImportantData}} - {{button.yetMoreImportantData}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**btn.component.ts**

```
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
    style;
    hovered;

    ...

    private buttonStyle(button) {
        let btnType = this.setBtnType(button);

        this.style = {
            'color': '#' + button.textColor,
            'font-size': button.textSize + 'px',
            'background-color': btnType.background
        };
        return this.style;
    }

    private pressedStyle(button) {
        let pressed = this.setBtnType(button, this.hovered);
        this.style['background-color'] = pressed.background;

        return this.style;
    }

    private setBtnType(button, hovered?) {
        let type = 'normal';
        let btn = {
            normal: {
                background: '#' + button.backColor,
            },
            pressed: {
                background: '#' + button.backColor,

            }
        }

        if(hovered > -1) type = 'pressed';

        return {
            border: btn[type].width + ' ' + btn[type].color + ' ' + 'solid',
            background: btn[type].background
        };
    }
```

}

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: I used a variation of this but added hover property to my model as I didn't have each item as a separate component.

Answer (score 5):

`:hover` is a pseudo class, it can not be added using `style`. You should use CSS and `ngClass` or `[class.xxxx]=".."`.

Comment: why do you think he wants to set `:hover`? I was thinking he wants to change button styles when hovered

Comment: Button has more than 2 states: normal, hover, focused, disabled, active. Current approach with `ngStyle` will fail in the end.

Answer (score 3):

The article https://css-tricks.com/css-attr-function-got-nothin-custom-properties/ pushed me on the right direction…

```html
<button class="btn register-button" [ngStyle]="styles"></button>
```

```scss
.register-button {
    color: var(--register-button--color, #999);
    background-color: var(--register-button--background-color, transparent);

    :hover {
        color: var(--register-button--hover-color, #555);
        background-color: var(--register-button--hover-background-color, rgba(0, 0, 0 / 10%);
    }
}
```

```js
    get styles(): Record<string, string> {
        return {
            '--register-button--color': this.configuration?.color || 'red',
            '--register-button--background-color': this.configuration?.backgroundColor || 'black',
            '--register-button--hover-color': this.configuration?.hoverColor || 'blue',
            '--register-button--hover-background-color': this.configuration?.hoverBackgroundColor || 'gray',
        };
    }
```

The trick is to use CSS variables, that can be set by `ngStyle`. Nice!

Comment: Great, thank you! clean and powerful solution

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use [style.backgroundColor] in html an the :not(:hover) on css

```
  <label
    *ngFor="let item of items"
    [style.backgroundColor]="item.color">
    {{ item.name }}
  </label>


label:not(:hover) {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```